# Java can't scan relative location of as txt file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm doing an assignment currently where I have to scan a text file (balance.txt). I've done this successfully but only with the absolute location, and when I try to specify the location relatively (in the folder i'll be submitting) it comes up with:

"Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: balance.txt"

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(Paths.get("balance.txt"));
}
}
```

I plan on submitting a zip folder which has the folder 'ATMAPP'. Within this folder is 'ATMAPP.java' and 'balance.txt'.

I've also tried suggestions such as '../' and './' but nothing seems to be working.

If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try it with `src\path\to\txtx`

Comment: How are you running your program? Which directory are you in when you do it?

Comment: please give your project structure and how you run your code

Answer (score 0):

It is actually working as you are expecting. If you run it via an IDE search for the .class file and make sure the 'balance.txt' is next to it. But try to run your code via console.

Go into your folder 'ATMAPP' and verify that the .class file is in the folder and type `java Main`.
Your application will startup and stop immediately.

I added some `System.out` to print the content of the file.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     Scanner reader = new Scanner(Paths.get("balance.txt"));

     while (reader.hasNext()){
         String s = reader.next();
         System.out.println(s);
     }
     reader.close();
   }
}
```